# how to convert a 24 bit (integer value) to string and vice versa?

Tags: c++, string, casting, int

I have a requirement  to read first 3 byte data (24 bits) and convert it to a decimal value .
         eg .  my first three bytes are  0x00 0x00 0x0A . 
i need to read  this and get 10 as the value .
I will get the input as string  (c++ string class).  how can i do that in c++?

Note :Need to follow Big endian representation of integer value.
 i am not able to generate the Input also .

Edit my code
For generating  :

```
  stringstream lss ;
   int lNo =32 ;     // I know its 32 bit integer value
   lss<<lNo ;   //string to int  
   // got output  in  lss.str()       as 32       . size of the string is 2 .
    // Expected out put is  0x00000020          size of the string should be 4 ..
```

so i tried the below code also

```
 stringstream lss ;
  char a[3] ={0x00,0x00,0x0A} ;
  lss<<a ;
 // this time output is empty string  ...
```

Comment: Does the string have hex codes in it (like what you typed above), or actual zero-valued bytes?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson i added the codes i tried

Comment: @RandallCook  no they will have only bit value not " hex string  " . I have to read  24 bits .

Comment: Do you want to interpret `FF FF FF` as 16777215, or as -1? Or for that matter as -8388607 or -0?

Comment: @SteveJessop i want that as  16777215

Comment: Good, that's what Randall's answer gives once it's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is this:

```
unsigned char a[3] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A };
int x = ((int)(char)a[0] << 16) | ((int)a[1] << 8) | a[2];`.
```

It is critical that the a array be unsigned characters so that they don't get sign-extended when converting them to ints before shifting them left. This does not apply to the first one, since it will presumably have a sign bit that is valid. Good luck.

Comment: Or use `long`, if you're at all worried about the kind of person who pedantically points out that to be properly portable you need `long` to ensure at least 32 bits ;-)

Comment: Oh, I missed it before. There's a problem here if `char` is signed on the implementation. You should mask each byte before shifting, or some equivalent.

Comment: Excellent comment about sign extension, @Steve. I just fixed my answer. BTW, on what platforms is `int` not 32 bits, where you would have to use `long`?

Comment: 16 bit hardware would be the place to look, for example PICs.